# gsub method and regex (case sensitive and case insensitive)

Tags: ruby, regex, case-sensitive, gsub, case-insensitive

In ruby, I want to substitute some letters in a string, is there a better way of doing this?

```
string = "my random string"
string.gsub(/a/, "@").gsub(/i/, "1").gsub(/o/, "0")`
```

And if I want to substitute both "a" and "A" with a "@", I know I can do `.gsub(/a/i, "@")`, but what if I want to substitute every "a" with an "e" and every "A" with an "E"? Is there a way of abstracting it instead of specifying both like `.gsub(/a/, "e").gsub(/A/, "E")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Hash. eg:

```
h = {'a' => '@', 'b' => 'B', 'A' => 'E'}
"aAbBcC".gsub(/[abA]/, h)
# => "@EBBcC"
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but more an other way to proceed: use the [translation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
'aaAA'.tr('aA', 'eE')
# => 'eeEE'
```

For the same transformation, you can also use the ascii table:

```
'aaAA'.gsub(/a/i) {|c| (c.ord + 4).chr}
# => 'eeEE'
```

other example (the last character is used by default):

```
'aAaabbXXX'.tr('baA', 'B@')
# => '@@@@BBXXX'
```

Comment: Why does this not answer the question?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I think he is looking for something like: `'aaAA'.buildInMethodOfYourMostCrazyDreams('a', 'e', FLAG_CASE_INSENSITIVE)` that returns `'eeEE'`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two variants of @Santosh's answer:

```
str ="aAbBcC"
h = {'a' => '@', 'b' => 'B', 'A' => 'E'}
```

**#1**

```
str.gsub(/[#{h.keys.join}]/, h) #=> "@EBBcC"
```

**#2**

```
h.default_proc = ->(_,k) { k }
str.gsub(/./, h) #=> "@EBBcC"
```

These offer better maintainability should `h` could change in future

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass gsub a block

```
"my random string".gsub(/[aoi]/) do |match|  
  case match; when "a"; "@"; when "o"; "0"; when "i"; "I" end
end
# => "my r@nd0m strIng"
```

The use of a hash is of course much more elegant in this case, but if you have complex rules of substitution it can come in handy to dedicate a class to it.

```
"my random string".gsub(/[aoi]/) {|match| Substitute.new(match).result}  
# => "my raws0m strAINng"
```